# migrate from Joda time library to Java time(Java 8)

Tags: java-8, jodatime

I am trying to migrate from Joda time library to Java time (Java 8). 
I am unable to find equivalent of `ISODateTimeFormat.dateOptionalTimeParser()` in `java.time`

Joda ISO formatter has nice parsers:

`ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()` : generic - selects parser based on string parsed.
Similarly:
`ISODateTimeFormat.dateOptionalTimeParser()`.

I am finding it difficult to change Joda time to java.time.
Can some one guide me?

example:

```
String dateTimeString = "2015-01-01T12:29:22+00:00"; 
String dateTimeString2 = "2015-01-01T12:29:22";
```

When I parse this string using joda time then

```
ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().withZone("EST")
```

can handle both without as problem. Which is equivalent of this in java time?

Using java 8,  ZonedDateTime with ISO_Zoned_date_time is not able to handle both.

Comment: May I ask you why you want to migrate? Is there a special problem in Joda-Time which you hope to solve with migration? As you can see in my answer, the migration can be a challenge in real practice. If you don't have any particular problem with Joda-Time and only want to migrate because Java-8 is more 'modern' then this might not be worth all the efforts.

Comment: Yes, you are right. We want to use all the modern features of Java 8 and this is why we migrating to java 8.

Comment: @MenoHochschild From the joda-time site _From Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310)._ Also from the site _Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)._ These recommendations both appear on the home page. It is wise to migrate if using Java8 (or higher).

Comment: @BillTurner I am very well aware of these official recommendations which make Joda-Time de facto outdated. Nevertheless, doing the extra migration work on a bigger Joda-based software is still a decision which needs to be justified not only by "going to a more modern library". Support of features which might get lost (for example intervals or duration/period-formatting) and unexpected behaviour changes in details (see my answer) are important issues, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use a predefined formatter but you can construct your own one (and assign it to a static constant) using following pattern:

```
static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_OPTIONAL_OFFSET =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[xxx]");
```

**Attention:** If you parse an input containing only date and time but without offset (and without any offset/zone-default) then the result can only be a `LocalDateTime`, not a global timestamp.

Please also note the different behaviour of method `withZone(...)`.

**Joda-Time**

> ```
> When parsing, this zone will be set on the parsed datetime.     
> A null zone means of no-override. If both an override chronology
> and an override zone are set, the override zone will take precedence
> over the zone in the chronology.
> ```

**Java-8 (JSR-310)**

> ```
> When parsing, there are two distinct cases to consider.
> If a zone has been parsed directly from the text, perhaps because 
> DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendZoneId() was used, then this override Zone
> has no effect. If no zone has been parsed, then this override zone will
> be included in the result of the parse where it can be used to build
> instants and date-times.
> ```

Side remark: The Joda-Time-method `withOffsetParsed()` is closer to Java-8-behaviour.

**Update:** I have now done my own tests. See the sometimes surprising results.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version")); // 1.8.0_31

// parsing s1 with offset = UTC
String s1 = "2015-01-01T12:29:22+00:00"; 

OffsetDateTime odt1 = DATE_TIME_OPTIONAL_OFFSET.parse(s1, OffsetDateTime::from);
System.out.println(odt1); // 2015-01-01T12:29:22Z --- OK

LocalDateTime ldt1 = DATE_TIME_OPTIONAL_OFFSET.parse(s1, LocalDateTime::from);
System.out.println(ldt1); // 2015-01-01T12:29:22 --- OK

ZonedDateTime zdt1 = DATE_TIME_OPTIONAL_OFFSET.withZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).parse(s1, ZonedDateTime::from);
System.out.println(zdt1); // 2015-01-01T12:29:22-05:00[America/New_York] --- seems to be a bug compared with the spec above, the parsed offset was overridden!!!

// now parsing s2 without offset
String s2 = "2015-01-01T12:29:22";

OffsetDateTime odt2 = DATE_TIME_OPTIONAL_OFFSET.parse(s2, OffsetDateTime::from);
System.out.println(odt2); // 2015-01-01T12:29:22Z --- questionable, the offset Z is invented/guessed here

LocalDateTime ldt2 = DATE_TIME_OPTIONAL_OFFSET.parse(s2, LocalDateTime::from);
System.out.println(ldt2); // 2015-01-01T12:29:22 --- OK

DATE_TIME_OPTIONAL_OFFSET.withZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).parse(s2, ZonedDateTime::from);
// throws an exception --- seems to be a bug compared with the spec above, the zone set was not accepted
```

**Conclusion:**

I would be careful when migrating. The devil is in the details. Maybe a newer Java-version 8u40 has meanwhile corrected some of the problems shown (at least the behaviour of `withZone()` is probably corrected - see [JDK-issue 8033662](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8033662), but for 8u31 the backport fix appears to be missing?!). You should also note that your "timezone" labelled "EST" was replaced by "America/New_York" in my tests because "EST" is not a recognized timezone id (it is rather a localized timezone name abbreviation in US).

**Update - final solution**

After extra testing this code seems to work in Java 8u31 (assuming UTC as default in case of missing offset in input):

```
static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_OPTIONAL_OFFSET =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[xxx]");      
OffsetDateTime odt = 
  DATE_TIME_OPTIONAL_OFFSET.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).parse(input, OffsetDateTime::from);
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.toZonedDateTime(); // containing a fixed offset
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a similar problem trying to convert ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().parseDateTime("...") to an equivalent based on the Java 8 java.time facilities.
In the end I failed to reproduce the behavior of Joda-Time's ISODateTimeFormat using a DateTimeFormatter and instead opted for a regexp based approach:

```
private static final Pattern ISO_8601_PARSE = Pattern.compile(
        "(?<year>\\d{1,4})-(?<month>\\d{1,2})-(?<day>\\d{1,2})"
        + "(T((?<hour>\\d{1,2})(\\:(?<minute>\\d{1,2})(\\:(?<second>\\d{1,2})(\\.(?<millis>\\d{1,3}))?Z?)?)?)?)?");

public static Date parseIso8601Date(String date) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Matcher matcher = ISO_8601_PARSE.matcher(date);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        try {
            String day = matcher.group("day");
            String month = matcher.group("month");
            String year = matcher.group("year");
            String hour = matcher.group("hour");
            String minute = matcher.group("minute");
            String second = matcher.group("second");
            String millis = matcher.group("millis");
            return Date.from(ZonedDateTime.of(
                    Integer.valueOf(year),
                    Integer.valueOf(month),
                    Integer.valueOf(day),
                    hasText(hour) ? Integer.valueOf(hour) : 0,
                    hasText(minute) ? Integer.valueOf(minute) : 0,
                    hasText(second) ? Integer.valueOf(second) : 0,
                    (hasText(millis) ? Integer.valueOf(millis) : 0) * 1000000, // nanoOfSecond
                    ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to parse [" + date + "]: " + e, e);
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to parse [" + date + "]; does not match pattern yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss[.SSS]Z");
    }
}
```

This is not 100% equivalent yet (i.e. it doesn't support "+00:00" style timezone offsets and instead assumes UTC), but it is quite close in how lenient it is when parsing the string.