# How does DateTimeFormatter's override zone work when parsing?

Tags: java, java-time

I'm confused by the `DateTimeFormatter`'s `withZone` method's behavior when it comes to parsing. According to it's documentation:

> When parsing, there are two distinct cases to consider. If a zone has been parsed directly from the text, perhaps because DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendZoneId() was used, then this override zone has no effect. If no zone has been parsed, then this override zone will be included in the result of the parse where it can be used to build instants and date-times.

Based on this and on the fact that `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME` parses time zones, I'd expect the following two tests to pass.

```
@Test
public void testNoZoneInInput() {
    final ZonedDateTime expected = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 2, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    final ZonedDateTime actual = ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-02-02T10:00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC+1")));
    Assert.assertTrue("Expected " + expected + ", got " + actual + " instead.", expected.isEqual(actual));
}

@Test
public void testWithZoneInInput() {
    final ZonedDateTime expected = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 2, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    final ZonedDateTime actual = ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-02-02T09:00:00Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC+1")));
    Assert.assertTrue("Expected " + expected + ", got " + actual + " instead.", expected.isEqual(actual));
}
```

But while the former does, the latter doesn't:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected 2017-02-02T09:00Z[UTC], got 2017-02-02T09:00+01:00[UTC+01:00] instead.

So it seems that the override zone is used whether a time zone is found in the input or not. I've found the similar behavior mentioned briefly in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30072486/5738696), when it's suggested that it might be a bug in JDK, but I haven't found a corresponding ticket on OpenJDK's bug tracker. Is it in fact a bug, or is my understanding of this documentation incorrect?

**Update**
I've tested this with java version 1.8.0_121.

Comment: Which subversion of Java-8 do you have?

Comment: @MenoHochschild: I've updated the question with this info.

Comment: Thanks. You have linked to my answer. Most of the problems I described there and observed for lower subversions have been fixed, but the problem with overridden offset (which matches your second JUnit-test) has obviously not yet been fixed resulting in a wrong time. Sad. For me, it is both contradicting the spec and also falsifying the temporal value of input (which is really bad). Have reproduced the problem for 8u72, too.

Comment: @MenoHochschild: thanks. So, your interpretation is that this is in fact a bug. While reassuring, it's also unfortunate - I happen to need this exact functionality. :) Do you happen to know if this is already tracked on OpenJDK's bug tracker?

Comment: This problem is not mentioned among the [open tickets of JDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20JDK%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20New)%20AND%20component%20%3D%20core-libs%20AND%20Subcomponent%20in%20(java.time%2C%20java.time%2C%20java.time%2C%20java.time)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug indeed, only not JDK-8033662, but rather [JDK-8177021](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8177021). It has been reported there that the assertion will fail for all Java 8 versions (I confirm that it fails with 1.8.0_172, the most recent one ATM), but pass with Java 9.